# Is there a way to create a fullscreen gallery on iPhone through Safari?

Tags: iphone, mootools, image-gallery, mobile-safari, slimbox

I've been creating CSS/Javascript to style an upcoming site differently on iPhone - mostly to enhance usability. On the desktop app, I use [slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox) in combination with mootools for an image gallery. This doesn't work on iPhone because it won't show the image fullscreen (safari chrome gets in the way). The solution I have at the moment is just to display image links.

I was wondering if there is some way to display images fullscreen through Mobile Safari - like the App Store and Photos.app. Anyone found such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You probably already know this - but you can get rid of the address bar with:
document.body.onload = function(){setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0,1);",100);};

To create the illusion of a native app even more, you can disable scrolling:
document.body.ontouchmove = function(e){e.preventDefault();};

Comment: I voted you up, but this isn't really what I want. Perhaps this isn't even possible until Apple come up with a solution to view fullscreen photos.

Answer (score 0):

There is a meta tag, [apple-mobile-web-app-capable](http://daringfireball.net/linked/2008/10/03/fullscreen-iphone-web-apps), that you can use to launch mobile safari in fullscreen mode. Keep in mind though that the user needs to add a web bookmark to their home screen in order for it to work, and any links they click on are sent to regular mobile Safari, which opens as a new application.

Comment: Even in the best possible use case, where 100% of visitors actually have bookmarked my site on their Home screen (extremely unlikely), I still need the browser chrome elsewhere in the site. So I'm looking for a solution in Safari if possible.